# Want to center content in the middle vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to center 'MAIN' content in the middle of the page vertically but whatever I do I don't know why it doesn't work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(img link) background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  .brandFont {
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
</style>

<body class='text-center text-white'>
  <div class='w-100'>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-dark bg-dark'>
      <span class="brandFont navbar-brand mb-0 h1">TEXT HERE</span>
    </nav>
    <main class='container'>
      <h1>
        TEXT HERE
      </h1>
      <h2>
        LONGER TEXT HERE
      </h2>
    </main>
  </div>

</body>
```

I have tried also with flexbox but it seems like the text doesn't want to move much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have made some changes in HTML : https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/PoGeJze

**FULL WORKING CODE:**

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.hero-wrapper{
      min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/367/267) center top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.navbar{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:yellow;
  padding:0.5rem;
  opacity:0.5;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<body class='text-center text-white'>
<div class='hero-wrapper'>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-dark bg-dark'>
        <span class="brandFont navbar-brand mb-0 h1">TEXT HERE</span>
    </nav>
    <main class='container'>
      <div>
        <h1>
            TEXT HERE
        </h1>
        <h2>
            LONGER TEXT HERE
        </h2>
        <p>People of this world are travellers</p>
      </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. it kind of works but I want to have page vh also with navbar. When someone loading the page, the user should see navbar and the text. With the code you have given me I can still scroll down and navbar isn't seen which shouldn't be this way. Don't know if you get what I mean

Comment: Hmmm. OKKK. Could you share with my the image of your final output my Friend. I will fix this for you... :) Once I get free... And it's a promise :) Just share the image.. I don't know the full context...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AuCDPLjRmRkNPP7t-nC-KJi69YtJs0yW?usp=sharing here is the link where are photos. I have added comment in them so you could better understand what is going on

Comment: yes, full height, without scroll

Comment: yeah, something like that

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried also with flexbox

Yes, you can achieve vertical centering in **CSS Flexbox** using:

- `flex-direction: column`
- `justify-content: center`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main class='container'>
  <h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
  <h2>LONGER TEXT HERE</h2>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you. it kind of works but I want to have page vh also with navbar. When someone loading the page, the user should see navbar and the text. With the code you have given me I can still scroll down and navbar isn't seen which shouldn't be this way. Don't know if you get what I mean

Comment: The code I've given you illustrates how to vertically align content in the middle of an element, using CSS Flexbox. That's the tool you need to put together your own implementation.